# Graduating Early

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, psychology

I am currently in my second year of college and since I came in with credits from high school college credit courses and AP credits I have the opportunity to graduate a year early. I would get my bachelors in 3 years and I am in a 5 year masters program where I would get my masters degree in one year as compared to two. So it would take a total of 4 years to complete my bachelors and masters. I am a psych major and I am a RA in a psych child cognitive and development lab. I am also getting into doing psych related volunteer work. Is graduating early hurting my chances of getting into a PhD program? If so what can I do increase my chances? Also I currently have a 4.0 Gpa.

Comment: Why do you think it could hurt your chances?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that graduating early would hurt, and it might even help. The things you say here indicate your seriousness. Keep up the good work. You should be fine.

Keep up good relationships with your professors, of course.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? There are lots of [similar threads](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=graduating+early) that say the opposite. (But all of them seem to apply for science subjects, so I don't think they are duplicates to this question.)

Comment: @GoodDeeds, the OP here doesn't seem to be leaving gaps. GPA, check. Research: check. Some of the others, such as math, suggest that they are going to miss some things by graduating early. There is no hint of that here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone likes a student who is good enough to make it through college a year faster than everyone else. So no, graduating early is not going to hurt your chances in anything you choose to do in life, getting a PhD included.

The only (small) caveat I would add is that grad schools do pay attention to things you might have done outside taking regular classes -- say, internships or summer research programs or working on a research project with a professor. If you have a chance to do any of these things, go for it